# How to write a cleaner version of "try catch" block in Python?

Tags: python, try-catch

*[After a few years into programming, I realized my question did not make sense at all:) Thank you for all your help anyway!]*

I have this code:

```
def try_(things):
    try:
        return things
    except:
        return None
```

But I want this call to produce the following result:

```
try_([1,2,3][2]) -> 3

try_([1,2,3][4]) -> Error  (But I want it to return None)
```

Comment: This is very unclear. A return by itself could never raise an error, so I don't understand what you are trying to catch. Please show your actual code.

Comment: If call `try_([1,2,3][4])`, then the exception happens before your `try_` function is called. It is impossible for `try_` to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the index as a parameter:

```
def try_(things, index):
    try:
        return things[index]
    except:
        return None
```

Call it like this:

```
try_([1,2,3], 2) -> 3

try_([1,2,3], 4) -> None
```